# Align comment in algorithm to the end of the line

Tags: algorithms, comments

Here is my algorithm:[image: algorithm]:

As can be seen the comment is aligned to the right end of the line.
I would like to align the comment to the end of the same line. At the exact place where the line ends I would like the comment to appear.
Here is the code:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,tabularx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}   
\begin{algorithm} 
            \caption{Bla Bla}
            \label{alg:ALG1}
            \begin{flushleft}
                \textbf{INPUT:} $N$ = no.   \\
                \textbf{OUTPUT:} Prediction of $W_{t_c}$    
            \end{flushleft}
            \begin{algorithmic}

            \\ BLALAAALALAdskjhfdsjk    \Comment{This is done as part}

            \end{algorithmic}
        \end{algorithm} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  `comment` can be changed via the macro `\algrenewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{...}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,tabularx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\algrenewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hspace{1em}$\triangleright$ #1}

\begin{document}   
\begin{algorithm} 
            \caption{Bla Bla}
            \label{alg:ALG1}
            \begin{flushleft}
                \textbf{INPUT:} $N$ = no.   \\
                \textbf{OUTPUT:} Prediction of $W_{t_c}$    
            \end{flushleft}
            \begin{algorithmic}

            \\ BLALAAALALAdskjhfdsjk    \Comment{This is done as part}

            \end{algorithmic}
        \end{algorithm} 
\end{document}
```

[image]